Find values which make two matrices congruent
For which values of $a\in\mathbb{R}$ are the following matrices congruent?
$$A=\begin{pmatrix} 1&4-a-a^2\\
2& -1 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$B=\begin{pmatrix} -a-1 & 3\\
3 & -5 
\end{pmatrix}$$

Clearly $B$ is always symmetric independently of our choice of $a$. Now, for $A$ to be symmetric it must hold that $-a^2-a+4=2$, and the solution to this equation are $a_1=1, a_2=-2$.
If $a=1$, $A$ has one positive eigenvalue and one negative eigenvalue, while $B$ has two negative eigenvalues. So, when $a=1$, $A$ and $B$ are not congruent
Now, when $a=-2$, $A$ has one positive and one negative eigenvalues, and $B$ has one positive and negative eigenvalue as well. The rank of both matrices is $2$. So, $A$ and $B$ are congruent when $a=-2$ (by Inertia Law).
Are there other values of $a$ that make these matrices congruent? For example, are there values of $a$ which make $A$ non-symmetric but still congruent to the symmetric matrix $B$? Or is this not possible?

Can you explain when two matrix are congruent?

If $A$ is congruent to $B$, then $A=P^{t}BP$. So $A$ must be symmetric .

@fusheng So it is correct to say that the only real value of $a$ that makes $A$ congruent to $B$ is $a=-2$, right?
